# Processing multiple values in each other's get property

Tags: c#

I am getting a StackOverflow exception on "return TimeOne".
The Timecheck method sets both values depending on their value at any given time. Is there a way to process both values at the outset based on each other?

```
 class Name
{
 private string _Timeone
  public string TimeOne
 {
       get
        {
           return _Timeone
        }


        set
        {
          TimeCheck();
          _Timeone = value;
        }
  }

 private string _TimeTwo
 public string TimeTwo
  {
       get
        {
            return _TimeTwo
        }

        set
        {
            TimeCheck();
            _TimeTwo= value;
        }
  }


    private void TimeCheck()
    {
           string WrongTime = "....";
        if (TimeOne == WrongTime  && TimeTwo == WrongTime )
                TimeOne = TimeTwo = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            else if (TimeOne == WrongTime) TimeOne = TimeTwo 
            else if TimeTwo == WrongTime) TimeTwo = TimeOne;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: as above?  It still causes a StackOverlow exception.

Comment: how does `TimeCheck` method look like?

Comment: You have to revise auto properties. This is in many ways wrong. You need to use auto properties. public string TimeTwo{ get; private set; } Set the value inside TimeCheck().

Comment: TimeCheck()   checks the values of both and if they are a certain time it resets them.

Comment: @John please show us the full code. If you made the changes as Ulugbek said properties should not be the properties wrong. Please give us the full picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by your setters calling `TimeCheck`, which in turn calls the setters, which calls `TimeCheck`, ad nauseum.

Break that cycle.

Your `TimeCheck` function can be rewritten so it sets the backing fields instead of calling the setters:

```
private void TimeCheck()
{
    string WrongTime = "....";
    if (_TimeOne == WrongTime  && _TimeTwo == WrongTime )
    {
        _TimeOne = _TimeTwo = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
    else if (_TimeOne == WrongTime) 
    {
        _TimeOne = _TimeTwo;
    }
    else if (_TimeTwo == WrongTime)
    {
        _TimeTwo = _TimeOne;
    }
}
```

This breaks the cycle.  Your setter can now call `TimeCheck` without fear of being called back in an endless cycle.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a stack overflow exception because your setters are calling themselves recursively with no end condition, when you do `TimeTwo = value;` Instead, you can create a private backing property for each public property and use those in the getters and setters:

```c#
private string _timeOne;
private string _timeTwo;

public string TimeOne
{
    get { return _timeOne; }
    set
    {
        TimeCheck();
        _timeOne = value;
    }
}

public string TimeTwo
{
    get { return _timeTwo; }
    set
    {
        TimeCheck();
        _timeTwo = value;
}
```

With your current implementation, each time you say `TimeOne = value;` the setter is being called again, which calls it again, and so on.

**EDIT**

I agree that `TimeCheck()` should not be called in the setters. Instead, I think it would be more appropriate to validate those values, and reset them if necessary, elsewhere. Maybe in a service of some sort, or whatever code is setting those properties to begin with.

Comment: That still causes a StackException.   I modified the code above.

Comment: I think you misread the code.  The setters weren't calling themselves.  The setter is `TimeOne`, and it set `_TimeOne`.  You basically just renamed some variables.

Comment: @Amy no, Matt is correct this is an endless cycle. He calls recursively the setter form the TimeCheck()

Comment: @panoskarajohn I know its an endless cycle.  This code is identical to the original, he only renamed `_TimeOne` to `_timeOne`.  That's my point.

Comment: @John please do not call the TimeCheck() inside the setter.

Comment: The original post didn't have backing fields. I didn't see those until after I posted my answer.

Comment: Where would the TimeCheck be called?  It has to be processed every time those values are changed.

Comment: @John see Amy's answer.

Comment: It actually seems to work when I modified the code as above!  Also the value has to be set BEFORE calling TimeCheck() so it has something to check :)    But is there any reason not to call TimeCheck() from the setter?   It's a JSON that is validated each time and I wanted that logic to be encapsulated within the same class as the fields.

Comment: Well, I just don't think business logic and validation belong in setters. If you validate it / set appropriately in whatever sets these values, you can prevent this object's properties from ever being in an inconsistent state. That's just the way I see it, others may disagree.

Comment: I was thinking of adhering to encapsulation and keeping the logic related to these value of these fields within this class.

Comment: Do whatever you're comfortable with. I'm not sure of your skill level. If I personally had logic like that, it would be handled by a service class of sorts.